# How do I blur an object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blur, illustrator-effects

[image]

I'm  trying get this blurry graphic effect in Adobe Illustrator but I'm not succeeding. Can anyone help me?

Comment: yes i try get this effect myself can you help me

Comment: What exactly have you tried

Comment: i try get this 3d cube with his many "pathes" for i get so cool blur effect

Comment: do you understand what i want?

Comment: I think you do not understand what we want to know from you. Please describe (tell us) what you have tried to build this effekt by your own ...

Answer (score 5):

Effect > blur > gaussian blur.

Turn it all the way up. If you want more blur than illustrator gets you, you should take your ai into Photoshop and blur it there.

Answer (score 0):

EFFECT > BLUR >
Then I put a rectangle around it (behind the object) that will be the color of my background.  Then I group it all together and right click and Export selection changing settings to 2300ppi then export asset.  After that, drag image back on to the artboard and image trace (using the high def) > expand > ungroup and delete borders.

Comment: it's already in the other answer. I don't see why are the extra steps necessary.

Comment: Maybe Lisas way provides more blur